# Как сделать индикатор загрузки страницы в %?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Пользовался гуглом, запрос, как взаголовке, но в найденной куче статей,  так и не нашел скрипт, который бы отражал процесс загрузки страницы.

Каким методом вообще отслеживается загружена страница или нет, ее состояние?
 Мне бы только это узнать,- есть ли способ отследить на сколько процентов она загружена, а уж визуально и на css подвязать смогу.

Понятно, что можно сделать заглушку, которая будет висеть 4 секунды и будет загружаться от 0 до 100%, ну а если интернет плохой и загрузка затянется в 4 раза.

За готовое решение буду благодарен (полоска от 0-100%)

Comment: [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981909/how-to-show-a-running-progress-bar-while-page-is-loading)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается заглушек, то их и реализуют в виде зацикленных анимаций только для того, чтобы не было явного окончания.

Что касается реального индикатора загрузки, то лично мне известно только один способ -

- всё грузить с помощью `XMLHttpRequest` и использовать его событие `progress`.

И самое главное, что нужно помнить, что не всем людям нравится группа Ария. Я это к тому, что не все могут оценить сложность реализации реального лоадера и многим он даже может не понравиться. Тем более нельзя забывать, что существуют приложения, которые реально нуждаются в лоадере, а есть такие, в которых его категорически нельзя использовать. Для пользователя важнее увидеть как можно быстрее контент за которым он приходит, а не прогресс загрузки.

***UPD: 0.0.1***

По поводу заглушки... Чтобы заглушка показывалась только до полного окончания формирования страницы используют события.

Если нужно, чтобы пользователь, как можно быстрее увидел сформированную страницу, используют событие `DOMContantLoaded`, которое посылается тогда, когда все скрипты загружены и `dom` полностью сформирован на столько, что к нему уже можно обращаться. Единственное, что не успевает загрузится, это картинки ссылки, на которые указаны в html разметке. Это подходит в 90% случаях, при которых на их место ставится красивая заглушка сигнализирующая, что скоро здесь будут изображения.

В тех случаях, когда изображение является частью приложения, то есть как в случаи с фоном на главной странице, используют событие `load`, которое посылается тогда, когда скрипты загружены, `dom` сформирован и все картинки загружены.

Отдельно стоит сказать что скрипты `js` библиотек добавляют в конце блока `body`, а на событие подписывают `document`.

Comment: А есть ли возможность повесить заглушку на то время пока страница полностью не загрузится? Ведь браузер показывает прогресс загрузки пока страница полностью не загрузится безо всяких аяксов

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Смотря как загружается страница:

Если грузится *САМА СТРАНИЦА*: апдейтим прогрессбар **по загрузке отдельных компонентов**: *скрипты, стили, контент*. Примерная реализация: повесить на выполнение каждого загрузочного модуля изменение шага загрузки:

```
var step = 0;//кол-во выполненых шагов
var total_step = 0;//кол-во шагов всего
var width = 100//ширина прогрессбара, когда он заполнен
function initJS(){
    step += 1;
    ...processing...
    total_step += 1;
}
function initSomethingElse(){
    step += 1;
    ...processing...
    total_step += 1;
}
function updatePBar(){
    $('#somePBar').css('width',total_step/step * width + 'px');//задаем ширину прогрессбара от кол-ва выполненных шагов
}
function initAll(){
    setInterval(updatePBar(),100);//каждые 0.1 секунду апдейтим прогресбар
    initJS();
    initSomethingElse();
    init...
}
initAll();
```

Если грузится *ЗАПРОС ОТ СЕРВЕРА*: апдейтим прогрессбар через **аякс**, там тоже методов немало. АТМ я и сам ищу решение этого вопроса, есть пара наработок в голове, но это если мы грузим контент на страницу после загрузки основной страницы, и подгрузки контента через сервер. Могу озвучить, если у тебя второй способ, вместе покумекаем.

Comment: А есть ли возможность повесить заглушку на то время пока страница полностью не загрузится? Ведь браузер показывает прогресс загрузки пока страница полностью не загрузится безо всяких аяксов

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов ну для меня самым оптимальным видится решение: грузить сначала _все самое базовое для заглушки_ - это там 5-6 строчек стилей и 1-2 элемента на странице, грузится быстро, верно? Затем, догружать под заглушкой остальную страницу, например формируя гденибудь на сервере, и получая ее тем же аяксом. Если без использования аякса - то можно попробовать грузить отдельные файлы(стили скрипты) через JS